# How to enter a single value in a vector of pair?

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, stdvector, std-pair

I am trying out a project in C++ and I am trying to enter a value from an integer type vector to a pair type vector.

I have tried `emplace_back` and `push_back` but it doesn't work. Most probably due to the pair typed vector.

Note: I am using boost libraries, not sure if that is helpful.

```
typedef unsigned int objecttype;
typedef string operationtype;

typedef unsigned int checkob;

typedef pair<objecttype, operationtype> objectops;

vector<vector<unsigned int>> parameters;
//lines returning values to “parameters”
vector<checkob> checkParams = parameters.at(0);    // works fine
vector<objectops> objectParams = parameters.at(1); // below error
```

The error message:

```
error test.cpp:273:30: error: no viable conversion from 'vector<unsigned int, allocator<unsigned int>>' to 'vector<model:: objectops, allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >>>'
stl_vector.h:326:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >::value_type' (aka 'std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >') to 'const std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > &' for 1st argument
stl_vector.h:344:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >::value_type' (aka 'std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >') to 'std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > &&' for 1st argument
stl_vector.h:383:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >::value_type' (aka 'std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >') to 'initializer_list<std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::value_type>' (aka 'initializer_list<std::pair<unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >') for 1st argument
```

Comment: Error says it: you cannot convert `vector<unsigned>` to `vector<pair<unsigned, string>>`.

Comment: You don't. A pair always contains two values.

Comment: Yes, but is their anyway with which this can be done?

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do. You appear to have two `vector<unsigned int>`s in parameters. Do you want the elements of `parameters[1]` to form the first part of corresponding elements in  `objectParams` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign `std::vector<unsigned int>` to `std::pair<unsigned int, std::string>`, which is obviously not possible.

You can either

- assign a vector of `std::pair<unsigned int, std::string>` to
  `objectParams`
- or a list initialization using a pair of the element of the *vector
  of vector of unsigned int* egers(i.e. `unsigned int`) of `parameters`
  and a `std::string`.

You probably mean this:

```
vector<objectops> objectParams ={ {  parameters.at(0).at(0), "string"} };
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    std::pair<objecttype, operationtype>
//                              ^^                                     ^^ for std::vector<objectops>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I want to add the value at index 1 of `parameters`
so will the code look like
`vector<objectops> objectParams ={ {  parameters.at(1).at(0), "string"} };`

Comment: If you meant the first element in the *vector of vectors* (i.e. element at `(0,0)`):  **NO**. `parameters.at(1)` means second row from `parameters`; i.e. `parameters.at(1).at(0)` -> the element at `(1,0)`. BTW your `parameters` is completly empty.

Comment: Yes, I meant the `parameters.at(1)`
I have few lines of codes which returns values to `parameters`

Comment: @SubhomoyMukherjee In that case, yes. By doing `vector<objectops> objectParams ={ { parameters.at(1).at(0), "string"} };`, the the first entry of the `objectParams` will get initlized with a `std::pair` of `unsiged int` and `std::string`, where the `unsigned int` is the element at `parameters[1][0]`(i.e. first entry of the second row)